# Run bash script as sudo from windows without interaction

Tags: ssh, bash, sudo

I need to execute a bash script as sudo on a remote linux machine from TeamCity running on a windows box.  I can execute the script fine from the cmd line using plink, but I am prompted for a password.  I need to be able to do this without being prompted for password in order to execute from teamcity.

What are my options?

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit the `sudo` configuration on the host you want to run the script. Run `visudo` as root and add a line like this:

`USERNAME        ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL`

Replace `USERNAME` with the user you want to run the script with. This should enable the user to use `sudo` without entering the password. You might want to limit the use of `sudo` to the commands you actually need. Look in the sudoers by using `visudo` for examples how to achieve that.

Comment: This prevents being prompted for a password when I have an SSH session but not when I use plink from windows : plink -ssh -pw {pwd} -t user@{ipaddr} /{dir}/{script}

Comment: ok, sorry. I guess I got your question wrong. So your problem is about providing the login password with `plink`? Have you tried providing the password with `-pw password` parameter? http://linux.die.net/man/1/plink

Answer (score 0):

If both systems are secured you can use something like this:

```
echo 'sudo_password' | sudo -S command
```

This option has to be used with care since it uses the password in clear and other users logged in into that machine might see it.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to just allow ssh access directly to the root account of the machine. You should lock this with a private key, and probably password protect that key. Add something like the following to your sshd_config:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
Match User root
  PasswordAuthentication no
```

If you go this route, you can make this key run the specific command script regardless of what has been specicfied by adding `command=""` in the ~root/authorized_hosts file, e.g.

```
command="/root/myscript" ssh-rsa AAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAADV4//KSz...
```